# Getting windows user name without using Windows auth?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, windows-authentication, .net-security

Is it possible to get the currently logged in Windows user name in ASP.NET MVC3 without using Windows Auth? I just need the login name, nothing else.

I'm building a quick and dirty dashboard app that will be used by my team. Some of the team's machines cannot be put onto the domain and I don't want the users to log in to use the system.

I've tried using HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name to no avail. I've also tried checking the request parameters, but they don't seem to contain this username.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get the currently logged in Windows user name in
>   ASP.NET MVC3 without using Windows Auth?

No, it is not possible. Well you could always put an input field in your application and ask the user to enter it. But there's nothing at the HTTP transport level that will provide you with this information if you don't use Windows Authentication.